# Adding a generated column with group by and count in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a table which has a store number and a fruit in it:

| Store Number | fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | Apple |
| 121 | Orange |
| 111 | Pineapple |
| 132 | Apple |
| 145 | Grape |
| 121 | Apple |
| 111 | Apple |

I want to to add a generated column "Number of Apples", which tells me how many apples are there in each store. Resultant table would look like this:

| Store Number | fruit | Number of Apples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Apple | 2 |
| 121 | Orange | 1 |
| 111 | Pineapple | 2 |
| 132 | Apple | 1 |
| 145 | Grape | 0 |
| 121 | Apple | 1 |
| 111 | Apple | 2 |

I am a beginner to PostgreSQL. Help me if anybody knows how to add this generated column in PostgreSQL

Comment: You will need to post some text showing the table and what your current query looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An actual [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/ddl-generated-columns.html) cannot do that - those cannot reference other rows, or use a subquery. They can use other columns in the same row, constants and immutable functions, but that won't be sufficient. What you need is a tally table `fruit_per_store` maintained by a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createtrigger.html) on your main `store_fruit` table, and a [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) that shows those counts where you want them. Unlike counting directly in the view, it's all incrementally updated, so it doesn't have to re-count everything each time you want to look at it.

[Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-_NA01zr):

```
create table fruit_per_store (
  "Store Number" int, 
  fruit text, 
  count_ int, 
  primary key("Store Number",fruit));
insert into fruit_per_store
select "Store Number", fruit, count(*) from store_fruit group by 1,2;

create function f_store_fruit_tally()returns trigger language plpgsql as $f$
begin
  if TG_OP in ('UPDATE','DELETE') then
    update fruit_per_store t set count_=t.count_-1
    where t."Store Number"=old."Store Number" 
    and t.fruit=old.fruit;
  end if;
  if TG_OP in ('UPDATE','INSERT') then
    insert into fruit_per_store as f
    values (new."Store Number",new.fruit,1)
    on conflict ("Store Number",fruit) do update
    set count_=f.count_+1;
  end if;
  return null;--it's ignored in `after` triggers
end $f$;

create trigger t_store_fruit_tally after insert or update or delete on store_fruit 
for each row execute function f_store_fruit_tally();

create view store_fruit_with_apple_counts as 
select s.*,coalesce(f.count_,0) as "Number of Apples" 
from store_fruit AS s left join fruit_per_store AS f
on s."Store Number"=f."Store Number" and 'Apple'=f.fruit;

select * from store_fruit_with_apple_counts;
```

| Store Number | fruit | Number of Apples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Apple | 2 |
| 121 | Orange | 1 |
| 111 | Pineapple | 2 |
| 132 | Apple | 1 |
| 145 | Grape | 0 |
| 121 | Apple | 1 |
| 111 | Apple | 2 |

```
insert into store_fruit values (111,'Apple');
select * from store_fruit_with_apple_counts;
```

| Store Number | fruit | Number of Apples |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Apple | 3 |
| 121 | Orange | 1 |
| 111 | Pineapple | 3 |
| 132 | Apple | 1 |
| 145 | Grape | 0 |
| 121 | Apple | 1 |
| 111 | Apple | 3 |
| 111 | Apple | 3 |

Answer (score -1):

You can use the window function `COUNT()` and `CASE` clause to performs a conditional count of the **Apple** fruits for each store number :

```
select store_number, fruit, 
       count(case when fruit = 'Apple' then 1 end) over (partition by store_number) as "Number of Apples"
from mytable;
```

A generated column can only calculate its value from other values in the same record. So what you are trying to do cannot be done with a generated column.

I suggest creating a `VIEW` :

```
create view nb_apples AS
select store_number, fruit, count(case when fruit = 'Apple' then 1 end) over (partition by store_number) as "Number of Apples"
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pXWa2KJt)

Comment: How can I add this("Number of Apples") as a generated stored column

Comment: I edited my answer, can you have a look

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to know the number of each fruit on each store you can get that quite easily with `GROUP BY`, `count(*)` and `FILTER` like this:

```sql
SELECT
  store,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE fruit='Apple') AS apples,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE fruit='Orange') AS oranges,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE fruit='Pinable') AS pineapples,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE fruit='Grapes') AS grapes
FROM
  data
GROUP BY store;
```

This would result like this:

| store | apples | oranges | pineapples | grapes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 145 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 132 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 121 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 111 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I know this is not exactly what you asked for but might be helpful.