# Generate sequential and distinct order numbers for vendors in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, distributed-computing, optimistic-locking

I'm working on an ecommerce app in a distributed system where multiple servers are interacting with a PostgreSQL database. I need to implement an order number counter for each vendor to ensure each vendor has its own unique and incremental order numbers.

Each vendor has a distinct sequence of order numbers, such as Vendor 1 having orders numbered 1, 2, 3... and Vendor 2 also having orders numbered 1, 2, 3... These order numbers are independent of the database IDs and are generated sequentially for each vendor.

I've considered using sequences and triggers, but I really dont know if it is the right approach. Also I have heard about optimistic locks and could help but I am not familiare with the implementation and I fear that locking the DB would cause some performance issues or would require creating optimistic locks failure handlers.
this is how to SQL data looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE vendors (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE orders (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
order_number INT NOT NULL,
vendor_id INT REFERENCES vendors(id));
```

So is there a way to do this ?

Comment: You really need to read [Create Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) especially the *Notes* section. In particular: *Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.*

Comment: In this scenario, gapless sequence is not required. So whenver a vendor is created  I need to add its own order_number sequence ? Also, is there a way to automatically assign the next sequence number to the vendor-specific order without handling it explicitly server-side? In other words, is there a way to automate this process during each database insertion, eliminating the need for manual steps like obtaining the nextval from the sequence in the backend, adding it to the order_number field of the Order object, and submitting the object to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Effective *ordinal number* per vendor

You'll need a [`view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) for that: if you try to only guard the consistency of that numbering through default values that are established on insert (either automatically db-side or by hand client-side), then a single delete, update, or non-default insert can break that consistency:

- A `delete` introduces a gap in the sequence of a vendor's orders - you said it's not a problem for you, but still, it's avoidable.
- Someone can `update` an order, reassigning it to another vendor or explicitly changing its number within the same vendor. In both cases that `order_number` will collide with another, future or existing, automatically-numbered order.
- It's possible to explicitly `insert` an invalidly numbered, out-of-sequence order. Depending on how you set up the default, [`OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.6.2) might not even be necessary.

A view can compute the current *effective* order of things, as of query time, using [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html#TUTORIAL-WINDOW), partitioned by `vendor_id`: [demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/u7vkZ-gM)

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
vendor_id INT REFERENCES vendors(id),
some_other_column TEXT);

CREATE VIEW v_orders AS 
SELECT *,row_number()over(partition by vendor_id order by id) AS order_number
FROM orders;
```

---

### Per-vendor *sequential identifier*

If those are just identifiers that you want to be sequential and unique for each vendor, then that's a fairly similar problem to keeping up-to-date, cached group counts ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77436183/5298879)). None of the standard methods help here:

- [`id serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)
- [`id int generated by default as identity stored`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY)
- [`id int default nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-DEFAULT)

All of them use a single, common sequence tied to the `id` column. A workaround is to use a function that accepts `vendor_id` as a "seed" and maintains separate sequences for each distinct seed, returning adequate `nextval()` based on that. Or, maintain a separate table holding the most recent id per vendor: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/OUBijmhM)

```
create table order_number_per_vendor(
  vendor_id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES vendors(id),
  max_order_number INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1);

create function f_order_numbers()returns trigger language plpgsql as $f$
begin
    insert into order_number_per_vendor as f
    values (new.vendor_id,1)
    on conflict (vendor_id) do update
    set max_order_number=f.max_order_number+1
    returning max_order_number
    into new.order_number;
    
    return new;
end $f$;

create trigger t_order_numbers before insert on orders 
for each row execute function f_order_numbers();
```

It makes no attempt at removing gaps or correcting manually broken sequences. Also, all concurrent `insert into orders` attempts for the same vendor, lock each other and have to wait for predecessors to finish. You can trade that for only locking if they all insert the first orders of a vendor: [demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/EGYzH3XR)

```
create function seeded_sequence_nextval(seed text) returns int as $f$
declare sequence_name text:='seeded_sequence_'||seed;
begin execute format('create sequence if not exists %I;',sequence_name);
      return nextval(format('%I',sequence_name));
end $f$ language plpgsql;

create function f_order_numbers()returns trigger language plpgsql as $f$
begin
    select seeded_sequence_nextval('orders_vendor_'||new.vendor_id) 
    into new.order_number;
    return new;
end $f$;

create trigger t_order_numbers before insert on orders 
for each row execute function f_order_numbers();
```

If a vendor already has a sequence, they'll all just call their adequate, dynamically constructed `nextval()`. If not, they'll all get locked until the first one finishes setting it up, then call `nextval()` on it.

It's tempting to try and use a function like that in a [`default`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-DEFAULT) or [`generated always as`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) expression, but the former can't reference any other fields to establish the shared seed, and the latter can't use non-`immutable` functions - which this one is not. It's [possible](https://dbfiddle.uk/NrcdFbwA) but not necessarily a good idea to try to falsely declare it as [`immutable`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html): that tells the planner it can potentially re-use a single evaluation of that `nextval()` throughout all rows of a statement. Even if it doesn't, it's technically allowed to:

> Labeling a function `IMMUTABLE` when it really isn't *might allow* it to be prematurely folded to a constant during planning, resulting in a stale value being re-used during subsequent uses of the plan.