# Postgresql trigger problem with unique key constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement of order no which need to start with country code + some running number which is incermenting

I did a trigger in following way. The order_no has a unique key constraint.

Now the issue I am having is that when there is concurrent order coming in. First order will be inserted and second order will be failed due to unique key constraint as 2 same order no generated.

What is the best way I can do this in database level?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_gen_order_no()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS
$$
DECLARE
    current_no INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO current_no FROM order_main dt WHERE dt.order_country_code = NEW."order_country_code"; 
    NEW."order_no" = CONCAT(NEW."order_country_code", TO_CHAR(current_no + 1, '000000FM') );

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER tgr_gen_order_no
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON order_main
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_gen_order_no();
```

Comment: Create a Sequence for Each Country Code and the modify the trigger function to use the appropriate sequence based on the country code. This will automatically handle concurrent requests without conflicts.

Comment: If you replace "country code" with anything else, that's a pretty frequent question. [Here are two methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77510834/5298879) from back when someone wanted to include vendor identifier in their sequential id.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't.

Persisted gapless, ordinal numbers for orders is a wet dream causing nothing but pain in reality. Very awkward for concurrent write access, and will cause problems with updates and deletes sooner or later.

Also keep country code and serial number in separate columns - each with appropriate data type, and the country code with a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to enforce valid states. For display, you can always (very cheaply) concatenate. If you must, add a generated column. See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived / generated columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-generated-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Use an `IDENTITY` column for the serial number. And be prepared to see gaps in the numbering after failed inserts / deletes / upodates. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

If you must have gapless numbers per country, create them after the fact in a view. See:

- [Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918552/serial-numbers-per-group-of-rows-for-compound-key/24918964#24918964)

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting [the answer in a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77510834/5298879) to your structure and the fact you want the `country_code` *in* the `order_no`: you can employ generated seed-based sequences. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/IA6I8GF1)

```sql
create function seeded_sequence_nextval(seed text, 
                                        owner_table regclass default null,
                                        owner_column text default 'ctid') 
returns int as $f$
declare sequence_name text:=concat_ws('__','seeded_sequence',
                                           owner_table,
                                           owner_column,
                                           seed);
begin execute format('create sequence if not exists %I owned by %s;',
                     sequence_name,
                     case when owner_table is null then 'none'
                          else format('%s.%I',owner_table,owner_column)
                     end);
      return nextval(format('%I',sequence_name));
end $f$ language plpgsql;

create function f_order_numbers()returns trigger language plpgsql as $f$
begin
    select concat(coalesce(NEW."order_country_code",'__'), 
                  to_char(seeded_sequence_nextval(NEW."order_country_code",
                                                  TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::text||'.'
                                                  ||TG_TABLE_NAME::text,
                                                  'order_no'),
                          '000000FM'))
    into new.order_no;
    return new;
end $f$;

create trigger t_order_numbers before insert on order_main 
for each row execute function f_order_numbers();
```

```sql
insert into order_main values 
  ('order2','CA')
 ,('order3','US')
 ,('order4',null)
 ,('order5',null)
 ,('order6','US')
  returning *;
```

| description | order_country_code | order_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| order2 | CA | CA000002 |
| order3 | US | US000001 |
| order4 | *null* | __000001 |
| order5 | *null* | __000002 |
| order6 | US | US000002 |

It doesn't mind if multiple concurrent transactions target the same country code and only locks briefly the first time a given country is entered into the table. [The demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/IA6I8GF1) also shows how to initially set up sequences for pre-existing country codes and set `order_no` for pre-existing entries. [Sequence ownership is handy](https://dbfiddle.uk/-xf4_8bw).

---

### If you don't mind gaps in your sequence,

because `delete`, `update` and rolled-back `insert` will cause them at some point anyways, use [*generated columns*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html): one [`identity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY), one regular: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nReijyrR)

```
alter table order_main 
  add column common_sequential_id int generated always as identity,
  add column order_no text generated always as 
    (order_country_code::text||lpad(common_sequential_id::text,6,'0')) stored;

insert into order_main values 
  ('order2','CA'),
  ('order3','US')
returning *;
```

| description | order_country_code | common_sequential_id | order_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| order2 | CA | 2 | CA000002 |
| order3 | US | 3 | US000003 |

As opposed to `concat()` and `to_char()`, `||` and `lpad()` are [immutable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html) and  can be used in that context. There are [slight differences](https://dbfiddle.uk/bgBxFo4v) in their behaviour.

Comment: Forcing gaps out of an identifier sequence (first example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77510834/5298879)) is effectively making it on ordinal number, which offers little utility: id of any given order will keep changing each time any order below it gets deleted or updated to move above it. `CA000002` becomes `CA000001` if you delete or move what was previously `CA000001`.