# psql - Resolve Duplicates without deleting, set max_identifier for the duplicates based on an account_id

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, psql, uniqueidentifier

I am attempting to address these duplicates without removing the second entry. I am seeking a solution where duplicate records of an identifier would be assigned the maximum identifier value for the account_id.

```
select account_id, identifier, count(*)
from books                                           
group by account_id, identifier   
HAVING count(*) > 1;

 account_id | identifier | count 
------------+------------+-------
        111 |        155 |     2
        111 |        198 |     2
        111 |        178 |     2
        111 |        167 |     2
        111 |        196 |     2
        111 |        156 |     2
        111 |        150 |     2
        111 |        223 |     2
```

For Example: (Processing only the first record)
(Consider the max*identifier as 223 based on the account*_id)
For the below record

```
 account_id | identifier | count 
------------+------------+-------
        111 |        155 |     2
```

it should set the identifier as (max_identifier+1)

```
 account_id | identifier | count 
------------+------------+-------
        111 |        155 |     1
        111 |        224 |     1
```

Likewise it should do this in the loop for all the records without breaking other Identifiers and records.

```
#
# Table name: books
#
#  id                 :bigint           not null, primary key
#  account_id         :bigint           not null
#  identifier         :bigint           not null

# Indexes
#  unique_account_identifier             (account_id,identifier) UNIQUE
```

Comment: Please share the schema definition of the `books` table (as `CREATE TABLE` SQL) in an [edit] to your question

Comment: @Bergi Added the schema

Comment: If you ended up getting these because you're trying to have individual, separate sequences of `identifier`s per `account_id`, you might be interested in these: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77510834/5298879), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77953276/5298879) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77855222/5298879). This sort of thing tends to happen if you try to achieve that by querying `max(identifier)+1` for each `insert`, either directly or in a `trigger` - two concurrent inserts in parallel transactions see the same `max()`, so they end up inserting the same value.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
UPDATE books
SET identifier = new_identifier
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    (
      SELECT MAX(identifier) FROM books WHERE account_id = dup.account_id
    ) + (
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY id)
    ) AS new_identifier
  FROM books dup
  WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM books orig
    WHERE dup.account_id = orig.account_id
      AND dup.identifier = orig.identifier
      AND orig.id < dup.id
  )
) to_update
WHERE books.id = to_update.id
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CbWa_4YO))</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Zegarek for providing the fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

```
with max_id as (select account_id,max(identifier) last_identifier from books group by 1
            )
            
update books set identifier = last_identifier + r_id 
from (SELECT id,last_identifier, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sub.account_id order by id) r_id
    FROM (
        SELECT id, account_id, identifier, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id, identifier order by id) AS rn
        FROM invoices
    ) sub
 left join max_id on sub.account_id = max_id.account_id
    WHERE rn > 1)a 
where a.id= books.id;
```

This resolved the Duplicate issue without Deleting.This Query updates the duplicates with the max_identifier of an acocunt_id.