# Postgres: Do not auto increment user "id" if "email" already exists?

Tags: postgresql

Having `id` as the primary key for a user when they sign up with an `email`, the `id` field is set to auto increment. It seems that when a user is trying to sign up with an `email` that already exists in the table, `id` will still increment, even though a new row is not created.

Is there a way I can prevent the `id` from incrementing if `email` is not unique?

Comment: make email unique and all problems goes away

Comment: In Postgres autoincrement fields are backed by a [Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createsequence.html) and per the link: *Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed.*  Every time you insert a record the `id` will sequence regardless of whether the insert was successful or not.

Comment: You could check if the email exists before trying to insert. But there's a race condition. If someone else inserts the email in the moment between your check and subsequent insert, then you're back to the original problem. This should be rare, of course, but it may still happen.

Comment: Side note about your use of sequences: it is generally poor security pratice to generate user ids with them; the predictable nature of sequences may help attackers get unauthorized access to data. Pseudo-random numbers are slower but safer. A UUID will allow you to get unpredictable ids with virtually no chance for collision. If your user count is low enough, a 64-bit integer is smaller to store, faster to generate and use in `JOIN`s and will also do well enough to avoid collisions (but you probably want to implement a fallback mechanism nontheless).

Comment: Apart from that, I concur with 2 of the previous comments: if you make emails unique, you can let a query report an error. Or use the [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause of `INSERT`; in **1 atomic query**, i.e. without race condition, you can check the existence of a mail and insert-or-update a record (or do nothing but that would be equivalent to getting an error). BTW, no system should rely on being able to save sequence values with no gap. Gaps are a natural thing you should not try to avoid.

Comment: And side notes about errors (sorry, that is a lot of comments from me...): the first type of errors many people encounter is `syntax error` when manually typing a query and it seems they consider errors returned by the DB to be something to avoid. However, most other errors are for the DB to let you know about the state of data inside it: syntax errors only inform you about your query, but e.g. a unique constraint violation is here to let you know data already exists **without the need to run a `SELECT`** first. You should see errors generated by your DB as a **good** thing.

Comment: As a general principle, an ID column based on a sequence should serve only as an identifier and should carry no additional semantic load, including as a proxy for relative temporal order. There are many reaosns why ID based on sequences might have gaps in their values; e.g., deleted rows and rolled back transactions. Why do you consider the gaps to be an issue?

Comment: @Atmo, `ON CONFLICT` will increment the sequence even in the fallback to the UPDATE as the attempted  INSERT triggers the sequence.

Comment: @nbk @Atmo The `unique` email is probably exactly how&why they get it: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PWBZV4Uk). `nextval()` is called before the constraint rejects the row, resulting in a discarded sequence element. I agree the only actual problem here might be OP's assumption about what `id` can and should be used for.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: Ah I missed the OP mentions the row was **not** being created, only saw the very last bit "email is not unique"... And yes, whether you get a unique constraint violation or use `ON CONFLICT` clause (with `DO UPDATE` or `DO NOTHING`), the sequence is being incremented; like I said, it is not something OP should try to avoid. If anything, user id fields are safer if they are generated randomly i.e. not in a sequence and the (often huge) gaps between ids are a protection against attacks.

Comment: There *is* a way to avoid touching the sequence: `merge`. [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1HwTPeaw). It's checking for matches before attempting the `when not matched` action, so it'll skip to `do nothing` without attempting the `insert` entirely, so `nextval()` won't happen either.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do, but the real question is: why? What is the purpose of having IDs without gaps? How is that useful? It is not. Just accept gaps in IDs.

Comment: @freakish The idea was to *both* answer the question *and* suggest a better question, offering some context and a better solution to the [underlying problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I admit to overshooting a bit with the word count. As to the why, I guess there's [the three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78133463/5298879) silly uses and plenty more but we all agree here that the PK shouldn't serve any of them.

Comment: While I cannot say it is technically the answer, that is, answered via SQL, I believe the correct answer, first suggested by @Atmo, is to not use a sequence for the id, but rather a `uuid`, as per security best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid *some* of the sequence skips due to rejected inserts if you replace the `INSERT` with a [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html). It's checking for matches *before* attempting the `when not matched` action, so it'll skip to `do nothing` without attempting the `insert` entirely: [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1HwTPeaw)

```sql
MERGE INTO users u
USING (values ('a@b.com')) t(email)
ON t.email = u.email
WHEN MATCHED THEN DO NOTHING
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (email)
  VALUES (t.email);
```

`Nextval()` just won't happen. `INSERT` normally calls it and moves the sequence even if it'll subsequently fail due to constraint violation or for any other reason. It'll also call it regardless of [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) actions.

A `merge` that fails or is rolled back after it ends up attempting to insert, can still give you gaps.

---

As established in the comments, you shouldn't consider those gaps a problem. Nothing you're supposed to use a primary key column for, should require that it's continuous or even in any particular order. You also shouldn't be concerned with *stored row order* unless you [`cluster`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) or play [*column tetris*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/5298879).

1. If you think it's a problem because you want something to indicate creation time, add a `created_at timestamptz` column with a `default now()`.
2. If you want continuous ordinal numbers, set up a [`view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) that'll give you `select *,row_number()over(order by created_at)`, not unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77510834/5298879).
3. If you plan to iterate over the table referencing consecutive `id` values, [`loop` over a query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) or a [`cursor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP) instead, if in PL/pgSQL. If in a [`recursive cte`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE), you can give them a `row_number()` first, then iterate over that.

An `id` in a [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) or [`identity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY) column can't be trusted to be continuous, or even ordered. If someone's pet is named "3rd mouse", it usually means they have a well-fed cat, not 2 more mice. There's also no guarantee the 3rd mouse isn't older than the 2nd is (would've been, if it wasn't for its untimely demise).

They're normally sequential and continuous only as a side-effect: it's just faster and easier to generate them like that, but the only goal is to keep them unique.

---

On top of the gaps you're getting, you can also get out-of-order `id`s if there are multiple clients operating concurrently (and caching):

1. Client A grabs `1` and `2`.
2. Client B grabs `3` and `4`, fails and issues a `rollback`.
3. Client C grabs `5` and `6` and commits their `insert` before A.
4. Client A commits their `1` and `2`.
5. Your `id` column now shows `5`,`6`,`1`,`2`. The oldest row is `5`, most recent is `2`.

You can tighten (not remove) the gaps if you `alter sequence pk_seq cache 1;` but the order can still break:

1. A gets `1` and doesn't commit yet.
2. B gets `2` and fails.
3. C gets `3` and commits immediately.
4. A commits `1`.
5. Your `id` column now shows `3`,`1`.

That, and any `update`, `delete` or default-`id`-overriding `insert` can also violate this fragile, accidental order.

Answer (score 0):

Just turning my comments into an answer to make it more readily accessible to future readers.

In the case of a user table and more generally in the case of any data a hacker would be interested in getting access to, **use a randomly generated number**; a sequence is bad security practice.
The predictable (although not perfectly because/thanks to the gaps) nature of sequential ids offers a vector for attackers to get access to unauthorized data.
Just Google [uuid vs sequential id](https://www.google.com/search?q=uuid%20vs%20sequential%20id) to get a sense of why this is important. You should be able to find reports about incidents that occurred partly because a critical identifier was a sequential id.

UUIDs are slower than sequence values and take more space too (they are 128-bit values).
However, such downside is easily offset by the security offered by random values (obviously, do not consider it to be the sole security measure you have to take).
 Also, they have virtually no risk of ever colliding inside 1 table.

On a related note, UUID v7 (a time-ordered version of UUIDs, see [here](https://buildkite.com/blog/goodbye-integers-hello-uuids) or the long [developer thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAGECzQR4iZmXUU9fNbvB%2Bwue0Y9CbnFoNYb%2BNrTnRuYVkMt-QQ%40mail.gmail.com#2b2db3c320cb7948cf6aee6026bb75dc) for some explanation) are expected to be delivered to Postgres 17. I am not completely clear about that yet (and will update my answer if I find some time looking at it) but basically, it would allow you to order values chronologically while keeping them random too.

You most likely do not need/want the ability to order your users by when they registered though but I suppose there are situations where it is useful.

---

For columns where sequential ids are suitable, you should accept there will be gaps in the sequence.

As was commented, a sequence-based primary key column should not have any semantic meaning attached to it; if it indeed has no meaning, it should not be an issue for you to have gaps (just make sure you choose a big enough integer type to store all the values required in the future).
Note that in some DBMS (e.g. Oracle), there is even no `ON UPDATE` clause you can attach to a foreign key. This way, you cannot mess up your schema by causing the update of multiple records in multiple tables by updating just 1 record in a master table (that is, with a `ON UPDATE CASCADE` clause).

Gaps occur for a number of reasons:

- When a record is deleted.
- When sequence values are generated in a transaction that is ultimately rolled-back.
- When the database is stopped/restarted.

Asking a DB to remember what values are discarded or skipped would defeat some of the main selling points of sequences: performance and parallelism.