# PostgreSQL: How to Enter/Update data in a column for each unique customer and increment it by 1 until the end of Table

Tags: postgresql, multiple-columns, dbeaver

I ask you to help me create a query (or Script) in the database (PostgreSQL). I want to write values in the "**number**" column, and so that *it increases by 1 value for each unique client*. I've searched all t
he data on the Internet, but I still can't figure out how to do it right?

My db looks like this:

| id | number | client_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 193079 | NULL | 001 | 100900.00 |
| 193080 | NULL | 002 | 81900.00 |
| 193081 | NULL | 003 | 76400.00 |
| 193082 | NULL | 004 | 64800.00 |
| 193083 | NULL | 001 | 51200.00 |
| 193084 | NULL | 002 | 111348.57 |
| 193085 | NULL | 002 | 159962.87 |
| 193086 | NULL | 003 | 379492.86 |
| 193087 | NULL | 004 | 223358.30 |
| 193088 | NULL | 003 | 379492.86 |
| 193089 | NULL | 001 | 465358.30 |
| 193090 | NULL | 003 | 125358.30 |

What I want is to wryte single "Update" query or script that will modity my table like this:

| id | number | client_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 193079 | 1 | 001 | 100900.00 |
| 193080 | 1 | 002 | 81900.00 |
| 193081 | 1 | 003 | 76400.00 |
| 193082 | 1 | 004 | 64800.00 |
| 193083 | 2 | 001 | 51200.00 |
| 193084 | 2 | 002 | 111348.57 |
| 193085 | 3 | 002 | 159962.87 |
| 193086 | 2 | 003 | 379492.86 |
| 193087 | 2 | 004 | 223358.30 |
| 193088 | 3 | 003 | 379492.86 |
| 193089 | 4 | 001 | 465358.30 |
| 193090 | 4 | 003 | 125358.30 |

I don't quite understand, should I use sequence and nextval functinality/correctly? Even If, I can/must use "sequence and nextval", I don't know how to use them properly!
Please help me!

I am using DBeaver to connect into my DB.
I tried several types of Update:

`UPDATE "myDatabase".myTable SET "number" =(CASE WHEN client = 001 THEN nextval(1) WHEN client = 002 THEN nextval(1)  ... CASE WHEN number is not null THEN skip ELSE 'skip this row' END END     );`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate sequential and distinct order numbers for vendors in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509146/generate-sequential-and-distinct-order-numbers-for-vendors-in-postgresql) Their `order_number` is your `number` column, their `vendor_id` is `client_id` in your case. That's to set that up to be maintained automatically. If you only want this as a one-off `update`, use window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this as a one-off `update`, use [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) and set up the window to be [partitioned by](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) `client_id`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/V94LNLSo)

```
with cte as (select id,row_number()over w1 as number
             from your_table
             window w1 as (partition by client_id order by id) )
update your_table this
set number=cte.number
from cte
where this.id=cte.id;

select * from your_table order by id;
```

| id | number | client_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 193079 | 1 | 001 | 100900.00 |
| 193080 | 1 | 002 | 81900.00 |
| 193081 | 1 | 003 | 76400.00 |
| 193082 | 1 | 004 | 64800.00 |
| 193083 | 2 | 001 | 51200.00 |
| 193084 | 2 | 002 | 111348.57 |
| 193085 | 3 | 002 | 159962.87 |
| 193086 | 2 | 003 | 379492.86 |
| 193087 | 2 | 004 | 223358.30 |
| 193088 | 3 | 003 | 379492.86 |
| 193089 | *this should be* **3** | **001** *this is the 3rd `001`* | 465358.30 |
| 193090 | 4 | 003 | 125358.30 |

Note the difference on your second row from the bottom: I think you wanted `3` in there.

Comment: THNQ very much @Zegarek! You helped me a lot!