# Why this trigger maximum sumatory returns all summed insted of only maximum

Tags: postgresql

i'm learning about postgresql recently, i've created a database with these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Batteries" (
  "Battery_id" int PRIMARY KEY,
  "Battery_Name" Varchar(255),
  "Brand" Varchar(255),
  "Cathode" Varchar(255),
  "Form_Factor" Varchar(255),
  "Capacity" Decimal(4,2),
  "Total_Cycle_Number" int,
  "Total_LifeTime" Decimal(4,2)
);

CREATE TABLE "Tests" (
  "Test_id" int PRIMARY KEY,
  "Test_Name" Varchar(255),
  "Battery_id" int,
  "Work_Group" Varchar(255),
  "Date" date,
  "Average_Temp" Decimal(5,2),
  "Max_SoC" Decimal(5,2),
  "Min_SoC" Decimal(5,2),
  "Charge_Rate" Decimal(5,2),
  "Discharge_Rate" Decimal(5,2)
);

CREATE TABLE "Cycle_Data" (
  "Mesure_id" int PRIMARY KEY,
  "Mesure_Name" varchar(255),
  "Test_id" int,
  "Test_Time" Decimal(12,3),
  "Cycle_Index" int,
  "Vmin" Decimal(5,3),
  "Vmax" Decimal(5,3),
  "Charge_Capacity" Decimal(5,3),
  "Discharge_Capacity" Decimal(5,3),
  "Charge_Energy" Decimal(5,3),
  "Discharge_Energy" Decimal(5,3)
);

ALTER TABLE "Tests" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("Battery_id") REFERENCES "Batteries" ("Battery_id");

ALTER TABLE "Cycle_Data" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("Test_id") REFERENCES "Tests" ("Test_id");
```

But the trigger is intended to take the new data introduced (with csv's from a python script) to the Cycle_Data, and do the following:

Iterate across new data after the insertion, select the maximum Cycle_Index (it's always the last value) for each different Test_id, then do a sumatory (+) on the Total_Cycle_Number on the Batteries table. The script is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_total_cycle_number()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    max_cycle_index INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT max("Cycle_Index") INTO max_cycle_index
    FROM "Cycle_Data"
    WHERE "Test_id" = NEW."Test_id";

    UPDATE "Batteries"
    SET "Total_Cycle_Number" = "Total_Cycle_Number" + max_cycle_index
    WHERE "Battery_id" = (SELECT "Battery_id" FROM "Tests" WHERE "Test_id" = NEW."Test_id");

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_total_cycle_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON "Cycle_Data"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_total_cycle_number();
```

instead of what i want it does a sumatory of all the Cycle_index for each Test_id

For more clarification, the csv's have the raw data of an experiment done for a battery, apart from loading all the data to the database to have it safe, what i want to archive is a easy way to check all the cycle done within all the experiments, so in the Total_Cycle_Number i want the summatory of the maximum cycle value of every test introduced. Think it's more clear this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate sequential and distinct order numbers for vendors in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509146/generate-sequential-and-distinct-order-numbers-for-vendors-in-postgresql)
 If it doesn't: **1)** Remove columns that aren't relevant to the question, the task you're carrying out. **2)** Add some sample/mock `insert` statements to show example input and show how you'd like that state to change after you run your operation, compared to an example of what you're getting now.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what exactly you're trying to achieve, but if that's separate "cycle number" sequences for each battery, you could also try doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78141363/5298879) in a statement-level trigger.