# Custom id sequence postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE notes (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  text varchar NOT NULL,
  primary key(id, user_id)
);
```

so I need postgres to create ids of records unique by user, but not by whole table. each user must have a record with id 1, 2, 3, etc.

example:

| id | user_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | any user's text |
| 2 | 1 | any user's text |
| 3 | 1 | any user's text |
| 1 | 2 | any user's text |
| 2 | 2 | any user's text |
| 3 | 2 | any user's text |
| 4 | 1 | any user's text |
| 5 | 1 | any user's text |
| 4 | 2 | any user's text |

in this example every user has his own sequence of ids his records, and the other user does not affect the sequence of his IDs.

in other words each user has his own records with separate ids like this user is the only person who creates any records.

for example, if user1 has 10 records, and then user2 created one records, id of this record must be 1, not 11 (because this is the first record of user2).

I've tried to create functions, triggers, sequences, but this did not give the desired result.

here is an example of what i've tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION note_id() RETURNS trigger as 
$$
 BEGIN
    NEW.id = (select max(id) from notes where user_id = new.user_id) + 1;
 END; 
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Update**

I am developing a telegram bot which stores notes. Any user can write it a message that contains a note that shall be saved. So that is why record IDs of a user shall not be unique in the whole table - when the bot shows notes to a user, the user sees the records ids starting from 1 (even if there're 200 records of other users).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate sequential and distinct order numbers for vendors in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509146/generate-sequential-and-distinct-order-numbers-for-vendors-in-postgresql) It's pretty much that, but you'll need to make `text` a generated column that concatenates the user's individual sequential identifier to `some_text_`.

Comment: @Zegarek thank you, i'll try tomorrow this solution. as for column `text`. in my example it has values `some_text_1`, `some_text_2`, etc, not because it's generated. this column may have any text - this is user's note. a user can save here "go to shop", "buy a cheeze" etc. so this is just a text

Comment: There's another one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954649/5298879).

Comment: Is it necessary the IDs be sequential integers? Could you use UUIDs instead? Do you just need a unique id or are you using it for ordering?

Comment: @Schwern preferably integers

Comment: @pizhlo Do they need to be sequential? Are you going to order rows using this?

Comment: @Schwern no, I'm going to order by created field

Comment: @pizhlo If we knew more about what you intend to use this for, we might be able to find a simpler solution.

Comment: @pizhlo If I understand, the situation is you have rows which are per user and ordered by a timestamp. You want a way to display "this is your 3rd note" to the user. Does [Generate sequential and distinct order numbers for vendors in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509146/generate-sequential-and-distinct-order-numbers-for-vendors-in-postgresql) not solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following updated `PostgreSQL` function and trigger

Function>>

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION note_id() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Obtain a session-level advisory lock based on user_id
    PERFORM pg_advisory_lock(NEW.user_id);

    -- Calculate the next id
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) + 1 INTO NEW.id FROM notes WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;

    -- Release the lock
    PERFORM pg_advisory_unlock(NEW.user_id);

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger -->

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_note_id
BEFORE INSERT ON notes
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION note_id();
```

Comment: It'll re-scan the table each time and it can still run into race conditions - there's nothing preventing concurrent sessions from seeing, fetching and using the same `max(id)`.

Comment: @Zegarek you are right, I updated the answer To address this, I used a mechanism that ensures atomicity and isolation for the id generation process

Comment: Thanks for addressing the remark. That's a step in the right direction but the way you set it up, it won't work: you're immediately releasing the lock after *reading* the `max(id)` while you probably want to release it only after you actually *commit* your newly established `max(id)+1` - so that whoever waited, will see the new, incremented `id`, and get their `+1` based on that. Right now, whoever got locked in the concurrent session will still get the same, common `id`, but now they'll both spend more time in the trigger, acquiring and releasing the locks, while they fail just the same.

Comment: You can check out [tis related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77510834/5298879), or [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954649/5298879). If you set up a separate tally table, it's enough to upsert to it from the trigger - the upsert will handle the locking on its own, plus you don't need to scan/check the larger main table. A step up from that are the "seeded sequences" which don't really have to lock at all except for the first generated id, when the individual sequence has to be set up.

Comment: @Zegarek Your statement raises valid points regarding the handling of locks. The criticism that releasing the lock immediately after finding the max(id) does not prevent concurrent sessions from getting the same id is correct. To ensure atomicity and consistency, the lock should be held until the new record (with the incremented id) is inserted, ensuring that subsequent transactions see the updated state.

Comment: Postgres doesn’t natively support per-entity sequences (like user_id-specific sequences), but you can simulate this with a tally table approach or by dynamically creating sequences. However, dynamically creating sequences for each user_id can lead to database clutter and management overhead. While the initial approach aimed to prevent concurrent transactions from generating duplicate IDs, the execution strategy needs refinement to ensure transactional integrity and system performance.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_note_id()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $f$
DECLARE
max_identifier INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(id)+1 INTO max_identifier
  FROM test.notes
  WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
IF max_identifier IS NULL THEN
    max_identifier := 1;
END IF;
NEW.id := max_identifier;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_trigger_notes
BEFORE INSERT ON test.notes
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION set_note_id();
```

Comment: See the exchange under [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78149180/5298879): this way you'd get race conditions and concurrent sessions inserting duplicate `id`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509146/generate-sequential-and-distinct-order-numbers-for-vendors-in-postgresql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77954649/5298879) you can see how avoid it.